# Accept server certificate for secured websocket connection

Tags: ssl, websocket, ssl-certificate

I am developing a secured Websocket server and realized that SSL at least requires server authentication.. That means, clients need to trust my certificates.
Is there a way to show up an "accept certificate" dialog at time the WSS is being established ?
What is the solution then ? Should I put the web application in an HTTPS connection ?
Of course I want to avoid having to manually send certificate to clients and asking them to trust it.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using a certificate from a CA trusted by most browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websockets are not normal sockets. They are established by upgrading an existing HTTP(s) connection, so if you have HTTP they will be unencrypted and with HTTPS they will be encrypted and all the certificate check is already done before the upgrade to WebSockets started.